# How to make left outer join a UD-function with any sql table? 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have a table. i have a user defined function(UDF). My UDF returns me a table. i need left outer join my table and my UDF table.

Answer (score 17):

Use SQL Server 2005's new APPLY clause. The APPLY clause let's you join a table to a table-valued-function. That let's you write a query like this:

```
SELECT  C.CustomerID, 
    O.SalesOrderID,
    O.TotalDue
FROM 
    AdventureWorks.Sales.Customer AS C
CROSS APPLY
    AdventureWorks.dbo.fn_GetTopOrders(C.CustomerID, 3) AS O
ORDER BY 
    CustomerID ASC, TotalDue DESC
```

The APPLY clause acts like a JOIN without the ON clause comes in two flavors: CROSS and OUTER. The OUTER APPLY clause returns all the rows on the left side (Customers) whether they return any rows in the table-valued-function or not. The columns that the table-valued-function returns are null if no rows are returned. The CROSS APPLY only returns rows from the left side (Customers) if the table-valued-function returns rows.

Source: [Using CROSS APPLY in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005)

EDIT: As Lieven mentioned, The CROSS APPLY is only necessary when you need to pass a value from your table to the UDF.

Comment: The CROSS APPLY is only necessary when you need to pass a value from your table (CustomerID in your case) to the UDF. A UDF without parameters can be joined like any other table.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer to reflect that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

If you do not need to pass a parameter to your UDF, you can simply join the table with your UDF. If you need to pass parameters, use the CROSS APPLY as mentioned in the other answer.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable yt
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UDF_YourUDF() yd ON yd.YourTableID = yt.YourTableID
```

Comment: <pre><code>select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,[Time]      
from      
( SELECT Page,Date,[user],      
        dbo.fn_GetActivityLogArranger2(Date,'halfhour') as [Time]      
        FROM scr_SecuristLog sl left outer join dbo.DefaultActivity2() da on da.[Date]=sl.[Date]     
) scr_SecuristLog      
where      
        Date between '2009-05-02' and '2009-05-03'      
      
group by [Time] order by [Time] asc   </code></pre>

<h3>Error:</h3>Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Ambiguous column name 'Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'Date'.

Comment: select Count(Page) as VisitingCount,[Time]      
from      
( SELECT Page,Date,[user],      
        dbo.fn_GetActivityLogArranger2(Date,'halfhour') as [Time]      
        FROM scr_SecuristLog sl left outer join dbo.DefaultActivity2() da on da.[Date]=sl.[Date]     
) scr_SecuristLog      
where      
        Date between '2009-05-02' and '2009-05-03'      
      
group by [Time] order by [Time] asc

Comment: But This query give me error:
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Ambiguous column name 'Date'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'Date'.

Comment: @Moheb, I know. I have added that requirement as a comment to the other answer 7 minutes before you wrote your comment (and downvoted this answer).

Comment: @ykaratoprak. If you need to pass a parameter from your table, you need the CROSS APPLY.